# Duplicate zip entry / unable to generate apk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, apk, android-proguard

Please I am trying to generate my apk file and I got this error
I dont know what should I exclude on my Gradle file

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'.
>
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\Hicham\Documents\DTISoftwares\Grounded\app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\debug\jars\3\1f\main.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Hicham\Documents\DTISoftwares\Grounded\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\24.0.0\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [android/support/v4/e/d.class == classes.jar:android/support/v4/text/TextUtilsCompat.class]))

Comment: More than one of your dependencies has included the support-v4 libraries. It's hard to help without seeing your gradle files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One/Some of the libraries files you have included already using support-v4 library.So remove line 
"compile 'com.android.support:...."
from the dependencies in your gradle file.

Answer (score -1):

skip the using of proguard. 
remove the reference of proguard file  from build.gradle.

You need to comment following line.

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('your file path'),
```

Comment: r u still getting the same exception ?